# Find the content of the xml tag in the same category as having another tag with Python elementTree module

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

my xml file looks like this:

```
<feed>
<doc>
<title>Main title</title>
<url>https://test.com</url>
<abstract>some text</abstract>
</doc>
<doc>
<title>Wikipedia</title>
<url>https://wikipedia.org</url>
<abstract>screenshot</abstract>
</doc>
</feed>
```

and this is my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import re

source = "simple.xml"
root = et.fromstring(source)


for child in root:  # read abstract tags
    title = child.find('title').text
    result = child.find('abstract').text
    print("{}: {}".format(title, result)
```

I want this output:

> ```
> Main title: some text
> Wikipedia: screenshot
> ```

but I can't get title tag content...

now I can't get xml file content by `et.fromstring(source)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f='''<root><doc><title>Main title</title>
<url>https://test.com</url>
<abstract>some text</abstract>
</doc>
<doc>
<title>Wikipedia</title>
<url>https://wikipedia.org</url>
<abstract>screenshot</abstract>
</doc></root>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(f)

for child in root:
    title=child.find('title').text
    abstract=child.find('abstract').text
    print('{}: {}'.format(title,abstract))
```

Output:

```
Main title: some text
Wikipedia: screenshot
```

The xml given was broken, so I had to add a `root` to make it complete, if you can paste the proper xml I can modify the code.

Comment: My xml file is fine, I just typed it wrong here(Updated). I also read the xml file from disk and if I use `ET.fromstring(source)`, this error is shown:
`xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 9`

Comment: Replace the line with how you initially read your xml. This is for reading xml from a string. In your case you are reading from a file.